# How to represent method reuse in sequence diagram?

Tags: uml, sequence-diagram

Need to reuse the method existing in a class.How can i create sequence diagram for this.
To explain elaborately, I have successfully represented the following scenario.
1. I have called a existing method belongiing to a class. I'm quite concerned in representaing the same when I call the same method for the second time

how to show method reusabiity in sequence diagram?

Answer (score 5):

It's perfectly fine to invoke the same method several times in sequence diagrams.

If you have a more complex reusable component, you can create [Interaction fragment](http://www.uml-diagrams.org/sequence-diagrams.html#interaction-fragment) to represent the reusable part and [use it](http://www.uml-diagrams.org/sequence-diagrams.html#interaction-use) in your `sequence diagram(s)` by utilizing `UML operator ref`.